# How to pass the path of a file to a Python script in a different directory

Tags: python, bash, zsh

I have a script in a different folder: `a/b/c/my_script.py`

I need to execute it in `x/y/z/` so that `my_script.py` will take the path of `x/y/z/my_file.txt`, modify it and open the same file in another folder: `x/y/q/w/e/my_file.txt`

How can I do that in Python?

I can do

```py
# my_script.py
import sys
argv = sys.argv[1]
// change the path
// open the file in the other path
```

then call `my_script.py` this way:

```
pwd
x/y/z/
python a/b/c/my_script.py $(pwd) my_file.txt
```

but I wonder if there's a better way.

Note: I've tried using bash function but it seems more complicated to parse strings.

Comment: did you already tried `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: I saw people suggest that but didn't. Yes, I think that will do. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried pkg_resources? it helps to locate resources inside packages. example: filename = pkg_resources.resource_filename('package_name', 'data.xml')

Comment: You don't need to pass your PWD to your script, because a process can find out its working directory by itself. But if you still want to do it for whatever reason, there is no need to create a child process (`pwd`)  for it, because the working directory is automatically stored in the shell variable `PWD`.

Comment: BTW, I don't understand why this question is tagged _bash_ **and** _zsh_.